# Countdown-Flipclock JS React.js | How to compare a variable(prop) to the same variable 1s ago?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, countdown, react-spring

i am building an animated Flipclock for a coding challenge in react.js using react-spring.

I built the animation and now i have to determine a trigger when to run the animation. Right now it is running permanently, as you can see here:

https://flipcard-countdown.vercel.app/

Every card for day, hour, minute, second is the same react-component that gets two props:

- measure: String with the name of the time-measure
- time: Number with the value to display

I am using react-spring so i can use a boolean to determine if the animation gets executed.

My plan was to check if the integer i am getting via props changes every second - by comparing it to the same integer 1sec ago. If it changes execute animation, if not ... you get the idea.

However i don't know how to do that. My initial idea using setTimeout() did not work.

Is there a way to save the value from the time-prop for one second and compare it to the newest instance of time?

Here is the code of the component:
And the repository (if of any interest):
https://github.com/janhenrikfock/flipcard-countdown/tree/animation

```
export default function Flipcard({ measure, time }) {
  Flipcard.propTypes = {
    measure: PropTypes.string,
    time: PropTypes.number,
  }

  const [previousNumber, setPreviousNumber] = useState(time)

  useEffect(() => {
    setPreviousNumber(time + 1)
  }, [time])

  const frontCardAnimation = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'rotateX(0deg)' },
    to: { transform: 'rotateX(-180deg)' },
    // Change the cancel boolean to determine if the animation runs
    cancel: false,
    delay: 1,
    config: config.slow,
    reset: true,
  })
  const backCardAnimation = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'rotateX(180deg)' },
    to: { transform: 'rotateX(0deg)' },
    // Change the cancel boolean to determine if the animation runs
    cancel: false,
    delay: 1,
    config: config.slow,
    reset: true,
  })

  return (
    <ContainerCard>
      <StaticCardTop>
        <span>{time}</span>
      </StaticCardTop>

      <StaticCardBottom>
        <span>{previousNumber}</span>
      </StaticCardBottom>

      <AnimatedCardFront style={frontCardAnimation}>
        <span>{previousNumber}</span>
      </AnimatedCardFront>

      <AnimatedCardBack style={backCardAnimation}>
        <span>{time}</span>
      </AnimatedCardBack>

      <Subtext>{measure}</Subtext>
    </ContainerCard>
  )
}
```

Thank you in advance to everyone taking time to have a look at this!

Greetings
Jan Henrik

Answer (score 0):

I ended up introducing another useState [cancelAnimation, setCancelAnimation] to trigger the animation like so. This triggers the animation reliably at the right moment.

I was hoping to use a previousNumber as a Trigger AND the displayed value when the card flips over, but that needs another solution now, since the way i set the previousNumber now is not correct in all cases.

```
export default function Flipcard({ measure, time }) {
  const [displayedNumber, setDisplayedNumber] = useState(time)
  const [previousNumber, setPreviousNumber] = useState()
  const [cancelAnimation, setCancelAnimation] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (time === displayedNumber) {
      setCancelAnimation(false)
      setPreviousNumber(time)
    } else {
      setDisplayedNumber(time)
      setPreviousNumber(time - 1)
      setCancelAnimation(true)
    }
  }, [time, displayedNumber])

  const frontCardAnimation = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'rotateX(0deg)' },
    to: { transform: 'rotateX(-180deg)' },
    delay: 1,
    config: config.slow,
    reset: cancelAnimation,
  })
  const backCardAnimation = useSpring({
    from: { transform: 'rotateX(180deg)' },
    to: { transform: 'rotateX(0deg)' },
    delay: 1,
    config: config.slow,
    reset: cancelAnimation,
  })

  return (
    <ContainerCard>
      <StaticCardTop>
        <span>{displayedNumber}</span>
      </StaticCardTop>

      <StaticCardBottom>
        <span>{previousNumber}</span>
      </StaticCardBottom>

      <AnimatedCardFront style={frontCardAnimation}>
        <span>{previousNumber}</span>
      </AnimatedCardFront>

      <AnimatedCardBack style={backCardAnimation}>
        <span>{displayedNumber}</span>
      </AnimatedCardBack>

      <Subtext>{measure}</Subtext>
    </ContainerCard>
  )
}
```